# The classical statement of class field theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The classical statement of class field theory is that for finite Galois extension $L/Q$ the following are equivalent:
a. $L$ is a class field.
b. $L/Q$ is abelian.
c. $L \subset Q[\zeta _n]$ for some $n$.
Here class field means for any unramified prime $p \in Q$ how the prime splits in $L$ depends only on the congruence class of $p$ modulo some modulus $N$ -which is a natural number.

I want to see this statement proven using the modern version either the idelic or the ideal theoretic, as something like a corollary.

$b \iff c$ is Kronecker Weber so that is fine (and the opposite direction is very easy).

It seems that (https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/a-class-field-theoretic-phenomenon/) proves that $a\iff b$. But I don't quite get the proof. Can someone explain how this works? maybe explain the central idea of the proof?

Comment: I would not call this "the statement of class field theory". It is certainly an important statement in class field theory, but the theory is far larger than that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof in the link(apart from a few typos) is perfectly detailed and clear. But I try to explain the main idea.

By Hilbert theory, you can understand the decomposition of $p$ in $K$ by looking at the $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ for example $p$ is unramified if and only if the inertia group is trivial. In this case decomposition group is generated by the $Frob_p$ and hence $r=[Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}):(frob_p)]$, and you can also compute f.

so the real question is to understand $Frob_p$. the class field theory says that if $K/Q$ is abelian then under the isomorphism $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})\to I_\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q}NI_K$, $Frob_p$ goes to the idele $(1,1,...,p,1,1,...)\in I_\mathbb{Q}$. so you have to understand the group generated by $(1,1,...,p,1,1,...)$ which seems even harder! but Kronecker-weber  says that $K\subset \mathbb Q(\zeta_N)$ so by compatibility of reciprocity map, and the explicit description of reciprocity map for the cyclotomic field, we see that we have to understand the group generated by $p$ inside $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*/H$ where $H$ is the subgroup of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)/Q)$ which fixes $K$. this shows that $b\to a$.

for the implication $a\to b$ the idea is that by the Chebitarov density theorem you have the density of the primes that spilt completely in $K$. now if every prime that decomposes in $K$ also decomposes in $L$ then $K\subset L$ otherwise the density of the splitting primes in $KL$ would be greater than it should be. now if $K$ is a class field,$p$ splits if and only if $p\in S$ where $S\subset \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ now $S$ should contain $1$(look at the last paragraph of the proof in the link) and hence every prime that spilt in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and hence $K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ which shows that $a\to c$

(I was a little careless and probably at some places implicitly I assume that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galios. but it is easy to fill the detail by the standard technics of Hilbert theory)